# Fail to install mongodb community edition on windows server

Tags: windows, mongodb, installation

I mistakenly installed mongoDB enterprise edition.
I removed the enterprise edition and tried to install the community edition and now I get the following message:

> You cannot install multiple editions for the same version of MongoDB....

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same thing, what i did is

- run RegEdit tool
- found "MongoDB" areas in Registry, two i dropped for me was:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-21-4166973794-2856464715-1933094435-500]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{FE313923-51D6-4FF6-AAF6-A78BEE1AF868}]

After that installer makes a clean installation

Comment: I have many records when I search for "MongoDB", did you remove them all?

Comment: I ended up deleting  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MongoDB\Server\3.2] and it worked